# Light bending around objects

Tags: optics

So, I have noticed that light bends around objects when held up in front of your eyes, and found this to be quite interesting as it makes objects and images sharper and easier to see. This is very pronounced for me, as I have a rare eye disease that distorts your vision more than glasses can even come close to fixing. I end up with a 'ghost' image of everything I see, as the light is hitting my eye and bouncing around places it shouldn't, causing secondary images of text and objects. While as far as I'm aware, glasses are designed to alter the way light is refracting across your eye lens, I am left wondering, if there is a way to reproduce the same effect you get when something is 'slightly' in the way, causing light to bend around it. I suppose the best example is, when I look through my glasses, and I tilt my head back so I'm 'just' looking over the rim of the glasses, all distortion of what I'm looking at is gone, and both eyes can see 20/20 and I can see everything perfectly and clearly. To tell you how big of a deal that is, one eye is 20/40, so that's a huge correction especially since every eye doctor I go to says there's nothing they can do to help that eye see any better, while the other is 20/25.

Would correcting something like this, require something more than what glasses tech can currently do? Is it possible to create something that bends enough light to see straight? Or would you need to have something placed within the eye so that as the light bends around it your vision is then corrected? I don't know of all the ways to bend light, so I look for ward to seeing what your answers to this will be. Thanks in advance, for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 1):

Light does diffract around objects. It does bend. [Diffraction of Light](http://alternativephysics.org/book/Diffraction.htm). [Diffraction](https://www.exploratorium.edu/snacks/diffraction) This does distort images around an edge.

Sometimes if I don't have my glasses, I can read by making a small hole with three fingers for light to pass through. You can see some diffraction going on, but the real reason for improvement is different.

Lenses, including the lenses in eyes, sometimes have a different focal length in the center and the edge. This is called spherical aberration. It means that light passing through the center of your lens might focus on your retina, but light passing through the edge does not. So using fingers to block light from the edge can improve things.

I don't know enough about eye diseases to say if this would help you.